# YouTube Player in Flutter Desktop (Windows)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I wanted to use YouTube Player in my app for both Android and Desktop. I created it using Flutter and now it is working properly. If I build it in windows, then it is running, but the player is not showing any videos.

I know flutter currently is not stable for windows. But other simple functionalities are working properly. However, I could not use YouTube Player for this. Does anyone have the solution or ideas for this problem?

Here is my source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  //AnimationController _controller;

  String video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfkFPedJ6UQ";

  YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //_controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);

    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(video_url),
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Programmer UZ")
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              YoutubePlayer(
                controller: _controller,

              ),


            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> But other simple functionalities are working properly.

The YouTube player package isn't simple functionality; it's using an inline webview plugin. As a plugin, it's based on per-platform code, so would need a Windows implementation, which it doesn't have. And implementing an inline webview plugin on Windows requires platform view support in the Windows Flutter embedding, which [doesn't exist yet](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31713).

There is currently no way to do inline web content in Flutter for desktop.